# why am I not able to see data with older date in my django project?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have written a small views through Django rest framework to populate database table data in between two different date range. Below is the code snippet:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework import permissions
from .models import Revenue
from .serializers import DataListSerializers
import datetime

class DataListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataListSerializers
    pagination_class = None
    queryset = Revenue.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def get_queryset(self):
        start_date = datetime.date.today()
        end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=6)
        time_filter = self.queryset.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))
        ser = DataListSerializers(time_filter, many=True).data
        return ser
```

After this I have manually entered the data in the database through admin page. So, those data are of current date. Now, I imported a CSV file in the SQLite which has data from the year 2017, and the file was uploaded successfully. There after when I refreshed the admin page, it crashed and I could see error as shown below:

```
    return datetime.date(*map(int, val.split(b"-")))
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

With this I assume that the over ridden logic written in the 'get_queryset' method is not optimal. Please suggest the optimal solution for the use case. Thank you.

Modified get_queryset

```
from dateutil import relativedelta

def get_queryset(self):
    start_date = datetime.date.today()
    end_date = start_date + relativedelta(days=6)
    time_filter = self.queryset.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))
    ser = DataListSerializers(time_filter, many=True).data
    return ser
```

But, I am getting below error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
[28/Apr/2021 16:46:31] "GET /api/time/ HTTP/1.1" 500 95252
```

Comment: did you try to add days using  `dateutil.relativedelta`
+timedelta here seems not working if you exceed the month
`end_date = start_date  + relativedelta(days=6)`

Comment: I modified the get_query method, but it gives different error now. Please check my original post, I have updated

Comment: `dateutil.relativedelta` is a module, `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta()` is a method

Comment: did you import datetime correctly: `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: @user3521180 All I can assume is you saved an invalid date into the database the error you get is from the function `convert_date` in `sqlite3/dbapi2`. This (saving invalid dates) is possible because dates are simply stored as strings in sqlite. Perhaps the date format of your csv file might have been wrong?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, yes, you are right, The data which I manually entered in the DB through admin page has the format yyyy-mm-dd, and the file which I had uploaded has the format dd-mm-yyyy. Unfortunately, I will have to work with later date format(from the CSV file). How to achieve that in our models. Because I will have to  modify the date field in models.py. Please suggest

Comment: @user3521180 you will have to at least store the data in the "yyyy-mm-dd" format in the database because that is what is expected to be stored in the column. You can display the date in various formats as you wish in the template by using the builtin template filters etc.